# How can I use JQ or JavaScript for a specific field in ODOO v8?

Tags: javascript, jquery, python-2.7, odoo, openerp-8

I'm newbie using JQ|JavaScript in ODOO, being honest never use it before!, I wanna implement a keylistener for a specific field, because when we define a field like `float` this field let you digit a lot of numbers(30 digits or more), even if you put in the definition of the field `size=7`, this is one of a lot of validations what I need to do, the Quality department is killing me!, I solved this issue hiding the float field and using a Char field to get more control! After a lot of search in training webs for ODOO no once teach you how to really JQ|JavaScrip is used for ODOO, even in the official documentation V8, It would be wonderful if you can explain me how use JQ|JavaScrip, and if is possible apply it only for a specific field, imaging we have 2 Char fields(char1, char2), how to apply only for char1, I'll really appreciate any help you can give me!!!

Something like [THIS](http://javascript.info/tutorial/keyboard-events#demo-char-uppercasing-input)

Answer (score 2):

**for this :**

add id for particuler field in xml

than add js code in js file like below:

```
openerp.module_name = function(instance) {

var QWeb = openerp.web.qweb;
    _t = instance.web._t;

instance.web.FormView.include({
    load_form: function(data) {
        var self = this;
        this.$el.find('#field id').on('change', function() {
            alert( this.value ); // or $(this).val()
            // here put your logic for validation field.
        });
        return self._super(data);
    },

});
};
```

Comment: Like I said dear Parikshit Vaghasiya, I never used JQ or JavaScript for odoo, please can you show me in a small example how can I use it, where create the .js, if I need to add to __openerp__.py etc, Thanks for your answer and for your time!

Comment: you have to make directory in your module like "module_name/static/src/js" and in js you create your js file . now u create xml in view folder in module where add js file to openerp. write code as below.





<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <openerp>
        <data>
            <template id="unique_template_id" name="String value" inherit_id="web.assets_backend">
                 <xpath expr="." position="inside">
                 <script type="text/javascript" src="/your_module_name/static/src/js/your_js_file.js"></script>
            </xpath>
        </template>
    </data>
</openerp>

Comment: just a one more thing, how can I get the `field id`? or what do you mean for `'#field id'`??? Thanks for your help!

Comment: in xml where u define your field like this : [ex: <field name="fieldname" id="field_id"></field>]

Comment: I understood we can add a id for a field, if we are working in a web module, specifically in the template, but what if I need to get the `id` for `partner_id` in the `sale module`? I tried to add `id=id_partner` but nothing happen, the id for `partner_id` is automatically generate. I don't working over a web module. I hope you can helpe!!!